# jQuery - manually slide top navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a top navigation div ("#nav") to display only on scroll up (with  jQuery). I've got this part working.
The part that I am struggling with is where I am trying to slideDown the "nav" by as much as the user scrolls up (by up to 100px). E.g. the user scrolls up by 50, so the nav should slideDown by 50.
This is how far I got... Let's say I am in the middle of the page at a scroll position 1000. Once the scroll up is performed by the user, I adjust the relative position of the top nav to 900 (1000-100 -> current scroll location - nav height) and then I start sliding the nav down. I managed to display the *entire* nav using:

```
var st = $(window).scrollTop();

$("#nav-wrapper").css('top', st-100);
$("#nav-wrapper").stop().animate({top: st })
```

I assume the desired outcome will need to be tied into by how much the user scrolls up. I could use some help with code.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                padding: 0;
                margin:  0;
                color: #fff;
                font-family: monospace;             
                font-size: 20px;
                background: radial-gradient(#DC4D53, #B40E0E);
            }
            #nav-wrapper{
                width: 100%;
                background: #333;               
                z-index: 5;
                height: 100px;
                position: relative; top: 0;
            }
            #nav{
                width: 1000px;              
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;             
                text-align: center;                                             
            }
            #nav-logo,
            #nav-menu {
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
            }
            #nav-logo{

            }
            #nav-menu{              
                margin-top: 35px;               
            }
            #ham-menu{
                float: right;
                margin-right: 200px;
            }

            #content-wrapper{
                width: 1000px;              
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;                 
                color: #fff;
                padding-bottom: 10px;                       
                overflow: hidden;
            }   

            #item1,
            #item2, 
            #item3 {
                height: 5px;
                width: 35px;                                                            
                margin-bottom: 5px;             

            }
            #ham-menu{          
                display: block;
                width: 35px;
                height: 25px;
            }


        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var lastScrollTop = 0;

                $(window).scroll(function(event){

                               var st = $(this).scrollTop();

                               if (st > lastScrollTop){ 
                                    // SCROLLING DOWN
                                    // do nothing - dont show nav on scroll down                                
                               } else { 
                                    // SCROLLING UP
                                    var slideDownFrom = st-100;

                                    $("#nav-wrapper").css('top', slideDownFrom);
                                    // slide in the bar (animation effect)
                                    $("#nav-wrapper").stop().animate({top: st })

                               } // else

                        // print current | last positions
                        $("#current").text("st: " + st + " | "+ lastScrollTop);     
                        lastScrollTop = st;

                }); // scroll()

            }); // docready

        </script>

    </head>
    <body style="">

    <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="current" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">position</div>

        <div id="nav">

            <div id="nav-logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">          
            </div>

            <div id="nav-menu">
                <div id="ham-menu">
                    <div id="item1"><img src="images/ham-slide-active.png" alt="slide"></div>
                    <div id="item2"><img src="images/ham-slide-active.png" alt="slide"></div>
                    <div id="item3"><img src="images/ham-slide-active.png" alt="slide"></div>
                </div>              
            </div>      

        </div><!-- nav -->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </div><!-- nav-wrapper -->


    <div id="content-wrapper">

        <h3>Home</h3>

        1) sample<br> 2) sample<br>3) sample<br>4) sample<br>5) sample<br>
        6) sample<br>7) sample<br>8) sample<br>9) sample<br>10) sample<br>11) sample<br>12) sample<br>13) sample<br>
        14) sample<br>15) sample<br>16) sample<br>17) sample<br>18) sample<br>19) sample<br>20) sample<br>21) sample<br>
        22) sample<br>23) sample<br>24) sample<br>25) sample<br>26) sample<br>27) sample<br>28) sample<br>29) sample<br>
        30) sample<br>31) sample<br>32) sample<br>33) sample<br>34) sample<br>35) sample<br>36) sample<br>37) sample<br>
        38) sample<br>39) sample<br>40) sample<br>41) sample<br>42) sample<br>43) sample<br>44) sample<br>45) sample<br>
        46) sample<br>47) sample<br>48) sample<br>49) sample<br>50) sample<br>51) sample<br>52) sample<br>53) sample<br>
        54) sample<br>55) sample<br>56) sample<br>57) sample<br>58) sample<br>59) sample<br>60) sample<br>61) sample<br>
        62) sample<br>63) sample<br>64) sample<br>65) sample<br>66) sample<br>67) sample<br>68) sample<br>69) sample<br>
        70) sample<br>71) sample<br>72) sample<br>73) sample<br>74) sample<br>75) sample<br>76) sample<br>77) sample<br>
        78) sample<br>79) sample<br>80) sample<br>81) sample<br>82) sample<br>83) sample<br>84) sample<br>85) sample<br>
        86) sample<br>87) sample<br>88) sample<br>89) sample<br>90) sample<br>91) sample<br>92) sample<br>93) sample<br>
        94) sample<br>95) sample<br>96) sample<br>97) sample<br>98) sample<br>99) sample<br>100) sample<br>101) sample<br>
        102) sample<br>103) sample<br>104) sample<br>105) sample<br>106) sample<br>107) sample<br>108) sample<br>109) sample<br>
        110) sample<br>111) sample<br>112) sample<br>113) sample<br>114) sample<br>115) sample<br>116) sample<br>117) sample<br>
        118) sample<br>119) sample<br>120) sample<br>121) sample<br>122) sample<br>123) sample<br>124) sample<br>125) sample<br>
        126) sample<br>127) sample<br>128) sample<br>129) sample<br>130) sample<br>131) sample<br>132) sample<br>133) sample<br>
        134) sample<br>135) sample<br>136) sample<br>137) sample<br>138) sample<br>139) sample<br>140) sample<br>141) sample<br>
        142) sample<br>143) sample<br>144) sample<br>145) sample<br>146) sample<br>147) sample<br>148) sample<br>149) sample<br>
        150) sample<br>




    </div><!-- content-wrapper -->



</body></html>
```

Comment: Any chance of making a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Have you considered using position:fixed on the nav after the user scrolls past some height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all your input.

I eventually got this working as expected (to a degree). This code works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox but the nav bar keeps "jumping" in IE 11 (there's a bit of lag) and it's not really performing well on mobile devices. So any performance improvement tips would be appreciated.

Here's the actual page online: http://dev.vlcek.me/sample6m.html

And here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {


            var lastScrollTop = 0;
            var curr = 0; 
            var scrollingDown = 0;
            var scrollingUp = 0;

            $(window).scroll(function(event){

                           curr = $(this).scrollTop();

                           if (lastScrollTop < curr){
                                // SCROLLING DOWN
                                $("#status").text('DOWN');

                                scrollingDown = curr;
                                $("#scrollingDown").text("Down: " + scrollingDown);



                                //$("#curr").text('curr: ' + curr);                         

                           } else{
                                // SCROLLING UP
                                $("#status").text('UP');

                                $("#nav-wrapper").css('position', 'relative');
                                $("#nav-wrapper").css('top',  curr - 100);

                                diff = scrollingDown - curr;
                                if (diff <= 100){
                                    $("#diff").text("diff (100): " + diff);
                                    $("#nav-wrapper").css('top',  (curr - 100) + diff );
                                }else{
                                    $("#diff").text("diff: " + diff);
                                    $("#nav-wrapper").css('top',  curr );
                                }                                                                       

                           }


                        lastScrollTop = curr;


                    $("#curr").text('curr: ' + curr);   


            }); // scroll()

        }); // docready

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have id's to your div's , so why don't to try to scroll to particular div by its id. I have explained this here : http://usmansidea.blogspot.com/2013/07/jquery-make-html-pages-scroll-able.html

What you have to do is to put the following function in your $.document.ready(function(){});

```
     function scrolView(i) {
         $('div').each(function () {
             if (($(this).attr('id'))==i) {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
                 }, 1000);
             }
         });
     }
```

and when you want to scroll to some particular div lets say its id is #nav-2 , the simply call  scrolView('nav-2'); , and thats it .Thanks